# Play video from TCP streaming source with custom frame headers

Tags: android, video-streaming, multimedia

I want to develop Android application which can play video from TCP streaming source with some custom frame header informations. Codec is H.263.

As I checked Android SDK, [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) can't be used because:

1. MediaPlayer can't use TCP IP and port as input URL
2. MediaPlayer can't parse custom streaming frames header information

So, I want to discuss with you which can be the best S/W arch. to achieve my goal. What I think about now is:

1. Implement my own streaming protocol handlers via TCP socket programming.

   - It will get data from TCP video streaming source and do parse of custom frames header
2. Use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) of Android SDK to decode H.263 encoded video frame.

   - I can't sure if this is right approach to take. Maybe, one another option could be ffmpeg
3. Render decoded video frame through OpenGL ES

Any opinion?

Thanks!